# Error on IStatefulServiceReplica.Open - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

We've got an actor service with two partitions. All of the idle secondary replicas are in a warning start with the following message from Service Fabric Explorer:

```
Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
Replica had multiple failures during open on _cp_3. API call: IStatefulServiceReplica.Open(); Error = System.ArgumentException (-2147024809)
An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Fabric.BackupRestore.BackupRestoreManagerFactory.GetBackupRestoreManager(IBackupRestoreReplica replica)
   at System.Fabric.BackupRestore.BackupRestoreManagerFactory.GetBackupRestoreManager(IBackupRestoreReplica replica)
   at System.Fabric.KeyValueStoreReplica..ctor(String storeName, LocalStoreSettings localStoreSettings, ReplicatorSettings replicatorSettings, KeyValueStoreReplicaSettings kvsSettings)
   at System.Fabric.KeyValueStoreReplica..ctor(String storeName, LocalStoreSettings localStoreSettings, ReplicatorSettings replicatorSettings, KeyValueStoreReplicaSettings kvsSettings)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.KvsActorStateProvider.OnCreateAndInitializeReplica(StatefulServiceInitializationParameters initParams, Action`1 copyHandler, Action`1 replicationHandler, Func`2 onDataLossHandler, Func`2 restoreCompletedHandler)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.KvsActorStateProviderBase.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.IStateProviderReplica.Initialize(StatefulServiceInitializationParameters initializationParameters)
   at System.Fabric.ServiceFactoryBroker.CreateHelper[TFactory,TReturnValue](IntPtr nativeServiceType, IntPtr nativeServiceName, UInt32 initializationDataLength, IntPtr nativeInitializationData, Guid partitionId, Func`3 creationFunc, Action`2 initializationFunc, ServiceInitializationParameters initializationParameters)
For more information see: http://aka.ms/sfhealth
```

We first encountered this error when moving from one partition to two partitions. Deactiving the node and removing the data was a temporary fix as the problem resurfaced with the next deployment.

The issue causes Service Fabric to constantly attempt to start the service which just stays in a perpetual cycle of "start, die, repeat".

I understand that a replica in an IdleSecondary state means it is currently getting data from the other nodes in order to be promoted to an ActiveSecondary. It seems to me the issue is related to getting the data from the other nodes for the actors.

What is causing this issue and how can I prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Repartitioning of ActorService is not supported. If you want to increase the number of partitions, you will need to delete the service and then create it again.

Can you share details about what Service Fabric operations you actually performed when you say: "*moving from one partition to two partitions.*"?